# Use of System properties and what is use of System properties

Tags: java, properties, system, system-properties

I have seen code :

```
public static final boolean SUPRESS_CHECK = "true".equals(System.getProperty("sdp.authz.disable", "false"));
```

1. what kind of use of this properties ?
2. why we have to use system properties setting and getting ?
3. when we should going to use system properties.

Answer (score 0):

These system properties are JVM wide parameters. If I take your example you can pass them when launching your VM:
    java -Dsdp.authz.disable=true -jar yourJar.jar

The default value for *sdp.authz.disable* is *false* unless you pass this parameter to *true*

This allows you to have the same code but change the behaviour of your app depending on the context (like dev or production)

Answer (score 0):

1. The java.lang.System.getProperties() method determines the current system properties. The current set of system properties for use by the getProperty(String) method is returned as a Properties object
2. If there is no current set of system properties, a set of system properties is first created and initialized.

Example:

```
      public class SystemDemo {

         public static void main(String[] args) {

        // this will list the current system properties
        Properties p = System.getProperties();
        p.list(System.out);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the java docs System properties are widely used to maintain the configuration of the application. we can use this properties to change the behavior of the application at run time.

Refer to the below link for more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Usage of system property:

Let's say that we have different databases server present for our application like QA, STAGING and PROD. The Database connection string for all these three database are different. So, There are two ways to set the configuration of the database.

1. Change the configuration in the code for the environment where application would be deployed.(Re iterative process, you have to change the configurations everytime you are changing the database server for the application)
2. Keep separate configurations in a properties file for every environment and based on the database which needs to be used, fetch the configurations.
   i.e. to understand better keep files like config_qa.properties, config_staging.properties, config_production.properties 
   Each file contains database configurations for qa, staging and production database servers respectively.

If we use the second point we would not be required to change the properties in the code everytime we deploy our code to a new database environment. This provides us flexibility to even make the changes to the configuration without compiling the code.